# Get numbers that only divide by 2,3 and/or 5, but not by any other prime number

Tags: c++, math

I am given an integer N and I have to find the first N elements that are divisable only by 2,3 and/or 5, and not by any other prime number.

For example:

```
N = 3
Results: 2,3,4
N = 5
Results: 2,3,4,5,6
```

Mistake number = 55..55/5 = 11..11 which is a prime number. As 55..55 is divisable by a prime different from 2,3 and 5, it doesn't count.

I guess I need a recursive function, but I cant imagine what the algorithm would look like

Comment: If 8 counts (`2*2*2`), why doesn't 4 (`2*2`)?

Comment: I don't think the ordering is that hard to figure out, it seems like it's a recurring sequence.

Comment: Yep, forgot, `2*2` also counts in.

Comment: You're basically asking for 5-smooth numbers, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number) on Wikipedia.  There are a number of ways to compute them correctly in order.

Answer (score 2):

The only numbers that are only divisible by 2, 3 or 5 are the powers 2<sup>*i*</sup> × 3<sup>*j*</sup> × 5<sup>*k*</sup> for *i*, *j*, *k* = 0, 1, ....

Those numbers are easily generated.

Comment: I've been thinking of this. But forgot to test it..
But there's a problem.. I need them in order from smallest to largest..

Comment: Nitpick - at least one of i,j or k has to be non-zero.

Comment: How should (i, j, k) be incremented? Of course it will start at (1, 0, 0) but what will be its successive values?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Oh OK, I thought `1` was also in the list. OK then. The difficulty is determining the ordering, I suppose.

Comment: @A.R.S.: Use the fact that `3 < 2 * 2 < 5 < 2 * 3 < 2 * 2 * 2 < 3 * 3 < 2 * 5` etc.

Comment: `2^2*3^0*5^0 > 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^0`

Answer (score 2):

The numbers you're seeking are of the form `2^n * 3^m * 5^k`, with n, m and k positive  integers, with `n+m+k > 0`.

I'd pre-generate a sorted array and just print out the first `N`.

Comment: I asked the same question on the other answer, but perhaps you could mention how (i, j, k) should be incremented from its initial (1, 0, 0).

Comment: There's the problem, making them sorted without extra numbers

Comment: @waplet you can generate the array in no particular order (for a max N) and then sort it.

Comment: I thought of way..
`cin << n;
int arr[n*3];
for(int i = 1 ;  i < n; i ++){ arr[3*i-3] = 2^i; arr[3*i-2] = 3^i; arr[3*i-1] = 5^i;}`
And then just sort?

Comment: @waplet C++ Doesn't support variable-length arrays. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Luchian-Grigore any deeper suggestion? It's only first month in C++ don't know how to use std::vector

Comment: @waplet you can probably get more support on how to generate the numbers in order on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

We can efficiently generate the sequence in order by merging the appropriate multiples of the sequence of Hamming numbers, that is the classical algorithm.

If `n > 1` is a Hamming number divisible by `p`, then `n/p` is also a Hamming number, and if `m` is a Hamming number and `p` one of 2, 3, or 5, then `m*p` is also a Hamming number.

So we can describe the sequence of Hamming numbers as

```
H = 1 : (2*H ∪ 3*H ∪ 5*H)
```

where `p*H` is the sorted sequence obtained by multiplying all Hamming numbers with `p`, and `∪` means the sorted union (so with `H = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, ...`, e.g. `2*H = 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, ...` and `2*H ∪ 3*H = (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, ...) ∪ (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, ...) = (2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, ...)`).

This algorithm has two downsides, though. First, it produces duplicates that must be eliminated in the merging (`∪`) step. Second, to generate the Hamming numbers near `N`, the Hamming numbers near `N/5`, `N/3` and `N/2` need to be known, and the simplest way to achieve that is to keep the part of the sequence between `N/5` and `N` in memory, which requires quite a bit of memory for large `N`.

A variant that addresses both issues starts with the sequence of powers of 5,

```
P = 1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, ...
```

and in a first step produces the numbers having no prime factors except 3 or 5,

```
T = P ∪ 3*T   (= 1 : (5*P ∪ 3*T))
```

(a number `n` having no prime factors except 3 and 5 is either a power of 5 (`n ∈ P`), or it is divisible by 3 and `n/3` also has no prime factors except 3 and 5 (`n ∈ 3*T`)). Obviously, the sequences `P` and `3*T` are disjoint, so no duplicates are produced here.

Then, finally we obtain the sequence of Hamming numbers via

```
H = T ∪ 2*H
```

Again, it is evident that no duplicates are produced, and to generate the Hamming numbers near `N`, we need to know the sequence `T` near `N`, which requires knowing `P` near `N` and `T` near `N/3`, and the sequence `H` near `N/2`. Keeping only the part of `H` between `N/2` and `N`, and the part of `T` between `N/3` and `N` in memory requires much less space than keeping the part of `H` between `N/5` and `N` in memory.

A rough translation of [my Haskell code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12482407/1011995) to C++ (unidiomatic, undoubtedly, but I  hardly ever write C++, and the C++ I learned is ancient) yields

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <gmpxx.h>

class Node {
public:
    Node(mpz_class n) : val(n) { next = 0; };
    mpz_class val;
    Node *next;
};

class ListGenerator {
public:
    virtual mpz_class getNext() = 0;
    virtual ~ListGenerator() {};
};

class PurePowers : public ListGenerator {
    mpz_class multiplier, value;
public:
    PurePowers(mpz_class p) : multiplier(p), value(p) {};
    mpz_class getNext() {
        mpz_class temp = value;
        value *= multiplier;
        return temp;
    }
    // default destructor is fine here
    // ~PurePowers() {}
};

class Merger : public ListGenerator {
    mpz_class multiplier, thunk_value, self_value;
    // generator of input sequence
    // to be merged with our own output
    ListGenerator *thunk;
    // list of our output we need to remember
    // to generate the next numbers
    // Invariant: list is never empty, and sorted
    Node *head, *tail;
public:
    Merger(mpz_class p, ListGenerator *gen) : multiplier(p) {
        thunk = gen;
        // first output would be 1 (skipped here, though)
        head = new Node(1);
        tail = head;
        thunk_value = thunk->getNext();
        self_value = multiplier;
    }
    mpz_class getNext() {
        if (thunk_value < self_value) {
            // next value from the input sequence is
            // smaller than the next value obtained
            // by multiplying our output with the multiplier
            mpz_class num = thunk_value;
            // get next value of input sequence
            thunk_value = thunk->getNext();
            // and append our next output to the bookkeeping list
            tail->next = new Node(num);
            tail = tail->next;
            return num;
        } else {
            // multiplier * head->val is smaller than next input
            mpz_class num = self_value;
            // append our next output to the list
            tail->next = new Node(num);
            tail = tail->next;
            // and delete old head, which is no longer needed
            Node *temp = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
            // remember next value obtained from multiplying our own output
            self_value = head->val * multiplier;
            return num;
        }
    }
    ~Merger() {
        // delete wrapped thunk
        delete thunk;
        // and list of our output
        while (head != tail) {
            Node *temp = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
        }
        delete tail;
    }
};

// wrap list generator to include 1 in the output
class Hamming : public ListGenerator {
    mpz_class value;
    ListGenerator *thunk;
public:
    Hamming(ListGenerator *gen) : value(1) {
        thunk = gen;
    }
    // construct a Hamming number generator from a list of primes
    // If the vector is empty or contains anything but primes,
    // horrible things may happen, I don't care
    Hamming(std::vector<unsigned long> primes) : value(1) {
        std::sort(primes.begin(), primes.end());
        ListGenerator *gn = new PurePowers(primes.back());
        primes.pop_back();
        while(primes.size() > 0) {
            gn = new Merger(primes.back(), gn);
            primes.pop_back();
        }
        thunk = gn;
    }
    mpz_class getNext() {
        mpz_class num = value;
        value = thunk->getNext();
        return num;
    }
    ~Hamming() { delete thunk; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cout << "Not enough arguments provided.\n";
        std::cout << "Usage: ./hamming start_index count [Primes]" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned long start, count, n;
    std::vector<unsigned long> v;
    start = strtoul(argv[1],NULL,0);
    count = strtoul(argv[2],NULL,0);
    if (argc == 3) {
        v.push_back(2);
        v.push_back(3);
        v.push_back(5);
    } else {
        for(int i = 3; i < argc; ++i) {
            v.push_back(strtoul(argv[i],NULL,0));
        }
    }
    Hamming *ham = new Hamming(v);
    mpz_class h;
    for(n = 0; n < start; ++n) {
        h = ham->getNext();
    }
    for(n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
        h = ham->getNext();
        std::cout << h << std::endl;
    }
    delete ham;
    return 0;
}
```

which does the job without being too inefficient:

```
$ ./hamming 0 20
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
10
12
15
16
18
20
24
25
27
30
32
36
$ time ./hamming 1000000 2
519381797917090766274082018159448243742493816603938969600000000000000000000000000000
519386406319142860380252256170487374054333610204770704575899579187200000000000000000

real    0m0.310s
user    0m0.307s
sys     0m0.003s
$ time ./hamming 100000000 1
181401839647817990674757344419030541037525904195621195857845491990723972119434480014547
971472123342746229857874163510572099698677464132177627571993937027608855262121141058201
642782634676692520729286408851801352254407007080772018525749444961547851562500000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

real    0m52.138s
user    0m52.111s
sys     0m0.050s
```

(the Haskell version is faster, GHC can optimise idiomatic Haskell better than I can optimise unidiomatic C++)

Answer (score 0):

there's always the brute force way:

```
int[] A = int[N];
int i=0;
int j=2;
while(i<N)
{
    if(j%2==0)
    {
        if(j/2==1 || A contains j/2)
        {
             A[i]=j;
             i++;
        }
    }
    else if(j%3==0)
    {
        if(j/3==1 || A contains j/3)
        {
             A[i]=j;
             i++;
        }
    }
    else if(j%5==0)
    {
        if(j/5==1 || A contains j/5)
        {
             A[i]=j;
             i++;
        }
    }
    j++;
}
```

for the "A contains X" parts you can use binary search in range 0 to i-1 because A is sorted there.