# New state of the art in unlimited generation of Hamming sequence

Tags: haskell, recursion, generator, primes, hamming-numbers

*(this is exciting!)* I know, the subject matter is well known. The state of the art (in Haskell as well as other languages) for efficient generation of unbounded increasing sequence of Hamming numbers, without duplicates and without omissions, has long been the following (AFAIK - and by the way it is equivalent to the [original Edsger Dijkstra's solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20060910152750/http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Ecs410aph/Lectures/Smalltalk%20II/Dijkstra%20on%20Hamming%27s%20Problem.pdf), too):

```
hamm :: [Integer]
hamm = 1 : map (2*) hamm `union` map (3*) hamm `union` map (5*) hamm
  where
    union a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) = case compare x y of
        LT -> x : union  xs  b
        EQ -> x : union  xs  ys
        GT -> y : union  a   ys
```

The question I'm asking is, **can you find the way to make it more efficient** in any significant measure? Is it still the state of the art or is it in fact possible to improve this to run *twice faster*?

If your answer is *yes*, please show the code and discuss its speed and [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) in comparison to the above (it runs at about *`~ n1.05…1.10`* for the first few hundreds of thousands of numbers produced). Also, if it exists, can this efficient algorithm be extended to producing a sequence of smooth numbers with *any* given set of primes?

(clarification: I'm not asking about the much faster [direct generation of an *n*th Hamming number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160054/849891), but rather generating all first *n* numbers in the sequence.)

Comment: 1. I would have expected an analysis like O(n log n), are you sure this is as bad as the polynomial you're suggesting? 2. Isn't this pretty much the state of the art regardless of language?

Comment: @DanielWagner 1. that's the empirical figure, check out the WP link (`~ n log n` is usually manifesting itself as `n^(1+a)` with low `a`'s ) 2. that *is* the question.... :)

Comment: @DanielWagner about your 1., the `a` in `n^(1+a)` for true `~ n log n` should diminish as `n` grows, but here the memory retention comes into play, and then bignum arithmetic starts taking its toll; so in practice the `a` for the classical code grows, for n = 100,000 ... 1 mil and up.

Comment: also, this is theoretically an `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: Related: [tag:smooth-numbers]

Comment: (I know this is from years ago with recent 2019 updates.) It appears from below that you knew the answer when you posted the question... was this just so that it could appear as an SO question for searchability?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe a. there are no recent updates unfortunately, just an over-eager neophyte bombing this entry with their non-answers. :( :( b. I just wanted to share this *"amazing"* new thing that I chanced upon on Rosettacode which ran twice faster than then best known comparable algorithm, to make it more widely known. :) SO was more loose those days, less formal, I think. I wrote it as kind of an advertisement, really.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a constant factor<sup>(1)</sup> speedup counts as significant, then I can offer a significantly more efficient version:

```
hamm :: [Integer]
hamm = mrg1 hamm3 (map (2*) hamm)
  where
    hamm5 = iterate (5*) 1
    hamm3 = mrg1 hamm5 (map (3*) hamm3)
    merge a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys)
        | x < y     = x : merge xs b
        | otherwise = y : merge a ys
    mrg1 (x:xs) ys = x : merge xs ys
```

You can easily generalise it to smooth numbers for a given set of primes:

```
hamm :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
hamm [] = [1]
hamm [p] = iterate (p*) 1
hamm ps = foldl' next (iterate (q*) 1) qs
  where
    (q:qs) = sortBy (flip compare) ps
    next prev m = let res = mrg1 prev (map (m*) res) in res
    merge a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys)
        | x < y     = x : merge xs b
        | otherwise = y : merge a ys
    mrg1 (x:xs) ys = x : merge xs ys
```

It's more efficient because that algorithm doesn't produce any duplicates and it uses less memory. In your version, when a Hamming number near `h` is produced, the part of the list between `h/5` and `h` has to be in memory. In my version, only the part between `h/2` and `h` of the full list, and the part between `h/3` and `h` of the 3-5-list needs to be in memory. Since the 3-5-list is much sparser, and the density of k-smooth numbers decreases, those two list parts need much less memory that the larger part of the full list.

Some timings for the two algorithms to produce the `k`<sup>th</sup> Hamming number, with empirical complexity of each target relative to the previous, excluding and including GC time:

```
  k            Yours (MUT/GC)               Mine (MUT/GC)
 10^5           0.03/0.01                    0.01/0.01      -- too short to say much, really
2*10^5          0.07/0.02                    0.02/0.01
5*10^5          0.17/0.06  0.968  1.024      0.06/0.04      1.199    1.314
 10^6           0.36/0.13  1.082  1.091      0.11/0.10      0.874    1.070
2*10^6          0.77/0.27  1.097  1.086      0.21/0.21      0.933    1.000
5*10^6          1.96/0.71  1.020  1.029      0.55/0.59      1.051    1.090
 10^7           4.05/1.45  1.047  1.043      1.14/1.25      1.052    1.068
2*10^7          8.73/2.99  1.108  1.091      2.31/2.65      1.019    1.053
5*10^7         21.53/7.83  0.985  1.002      6.01/7.05      1.044    1.057
 10^8          45.83/16.79 1.090  1.093     12.42/15.26     1.047    1.084
```

As you can see, the factor between the MUT times is about 3.5, but the GC time is not much different.

<sup>(1)</sup> Well, it looks constant, and I think both variants have the same computational complexity, but I haven't pulled out pencil and paper to prove it, nor do I intend to.

Comment: so yes, you nailed it. I'll post an answer later with more details. **Credit goes not to me**; I just came across it somewhere, and wanted to make it known. Notice that at lower range your speedup is not 3.6, but 3.3 and 2.8. What I have right now, gives a speedup of 2.5 at low range. But you've successfully reinvented this wheel, and made it even faster, it seems. I think this is an exciting news. :)

Comment: Within experimental error, I get the same times for the `fix` version and mine. Mine allocates about 200 bytes more and has slightly higher residency, but the figures are very close (no wonder, it's basically the same algorithm).

Answer (score 5):

So basically, now that Daniel Fischer gave his answer, I can say that I came across this recently, and I think this is an exciting development, since the classical code was known for ages, since Dijkstra.

Daniel correctly identified the redundancy of the duplicates generation which must then be removed, in the classical version.

**[The credit for the original discovery (AFAIK) goes to Rosettacode.org's contributor Ledrug](http://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Hamming_numbers&diff=143055&oldid=142784)**, as of 2012-08-26. And of course **[the independent discovery by Daniel Fischer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12482407/849891)** (2012-09-18).

Re-written slightly, that code is:

```hs
import Data.Function (fix)

hamm = 1 : foldr (\n s -> fix (merge s . (n:) . map (n*))) [] [2,3,5]
```

with the usual implementation of merge,

```hs
merge a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) | x < y     = x : merge xs b
                        | otherwise = y : merge a ys
merge [] b = b
merge a [] = a
```

It gives about 2.0x - 2.5x a speedup vs. the classical version.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was easier than I thought. This will do 1000 Hammings in 0.05 seconds on my slow PC at home. This afternoon at work and a faster PC times of less than 600 were coming out as zero seconds.

This take Hammings from Hammings. It's based on doing it fastest in Excel.

I was getting wrong numbers after 250000, with `Int`. The numbers grow very big very fast, so `Integer` must be used to be sure, because `Int` is bounded.

```
mkHamm :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] 
       -> Int -> (Integer, [Int])
mkHamm ml (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) n =  
   if n <= 1
       then (last ml, map length [(x:xs), (y:ys), (z:zs)])
       else mkHamm (ml++[m]) as bs cs (n-1)
     where
         m = minimum [x,y,z]
         as = if x == m then xs ++ [m*2] else (x:xs) ++ [m*2]
         bs = if y == m then ys ++ [m*3] else (y:ys) ++ [m*3]
         cs = if z == m then zs ++ [m*5] else (z:zs) ++ [m*5]
```

Testing,

```
> mkHamm  [1] [2] [3] [5] 5000
(50837316566580,[306,479,692])        -- (0.41 secs)

> mkHamm  [1] [2] [3] [5] 10000
(288325195312500000,[488,767,1109])   -- (1.79 secs)

> logBase 2 (1.79/0.41)     -- log of times ratio = 
2.1262637726461726          --   empirical order of growth

> map (logBase 2) [488/306, 767/479, 1109/692] :: [Float]
[0.6733495, 0.6792009, 0.68041545]     -- leftovers sizes ratios
```

This means that this code's run time's [empirical order of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) is above quadratic (*`~n^2.13`* as measured, interpreted, at GHCi prompt).

Also, the sizes of the three dangling overproduced segments of the sequence are each *`~n^0.67`* i.e. *`~n^(2/3)`*.

Additionally, this code is non-lazy: the resulting sequence's first element can only be accessed *only after* the *very last* one is calculated.

The state of the art code in the question is linear, overproduces exactly *0* elements past the point of interest, and is properly lazy: it starts producing its numbers immediately.

So, though an immense improvement over the previous answers by this poster, it is still significantly worse than the original, let alone its improvement as appearing in the top two answers.

**12.31.2018**

Only the very best people educate. @Will Ness also has authored or co-authored 19 chapters in GoalKicker.com “Haskell for Professionals”. The free book is a treasure.

I had carried around the idea of a function that would do this, like this. I was apprehensive because I thought it would be convoluted and involved logic like in some modern languages. I decided to start writing and was amazed how easy Haskell makes the realization of even bad ideas.

I've not had difficulty generating unique lists. My problem is the lists I generate do not end well. Even when I use diagonalization they leave residual values making their use unreliable at best.

Here is a reworked 3's and 5's list with nothing residual at the end. The denationalization is to reduce residual values not to eliminate duplicates which are never included anyway.

```
g3s5s n=[t*b|(a,b)<-[ (((d+n)-(d*2)), 5^d) | d <- [0..n]],
                t <-[ 3^e | e <- [0..a+8]],
             (t*b)<-(3^(n+6))+a]                                       


ham2 n = take n $ ham2' (drop 1.sort.g3s5s $ 48) [1]

ham2' o@(f:fo) e@(h:hx) = if h == min h f
                      then h:ham2'  o (hx ++ [h*2])
                      else f:ham2' fo ( e ++ [f*2])
```

The `twos` list can be generated with all `2^e`s multiplied by each of the `3s5s` but when identity `2^0` is included, then, in total, it is the Hammings.

**3/25/2019**

Well, finally. I knew this some time ago but could not implement it without excess values at the end. The problem was how to not generate the excess that is the result of a Cartesian Product. I use Excel a lot and could not see the pattern of values to exclude from the Cartesian Product worksheet. Then, eureka! The functions generate lists of each lead factor. The value to limit the values in each list is the end point of the first list. When this is done, all Hammings are produced with no excess.

Two functions for Hammings. The first is a new 3's & 5's list which is then used to create multiples with the 2's. The multiples are Hammings.

```
h35r  x = h3s5s x (5^x)
h3s5s x c = [t| n<-[3^e|e<-[0..x]],
                m<-[5^e|e<-[0..x]], 
                t<-[n*m],
             t <= c ]

a2r n = sort $ a2s n (2^n)
a2s n c =   [h| b<-h35r n, 
                a<-[2^e| e<-[0..n]],
                h<-[a*b],
             h <= c ]
```

`last $ a2r 50`

1125899906842624

(0.16 secs, 321,326,648 bytes)

2^50

1125899906842624

(0.00 secs, 95,424 bytes

This is an alternate, cleaner & faster with less memory usage implementation.

```
gnf n f = scanl (*) 1 $ replicate f n

mk35   n = (\c->      [m| t<- gnf 3 n, f<- gnf 5  n,    m<- [t*f], m<= c]) (2^(n+1))
mkHams n = (\c-> sort [m| t<- mk35  n, f<- gnf 2 (n+1), m<- [t*f], m<= c]) (2^(n+1))
```

`last $ mkHams 50`

2251799813685248

(0.03 secs, 12,869,000 bytes)

`2^51`

2251799813685248

**5/6/2019**

Well, I tried limiting differently but always come back to what is simplest. I am opting for the least memory usage as also seeming to be the fastest.

I also opted to use `map` with an implicit parameter.

I also found that `mergeAll` from `Data.List.Ordered` is faster that `sort` or `sort` and `concat`.

I also like when sublists are created so I can analyze the data much easier.

Then, because of @Will Ness switched to `iterate` instead of `scanl` making much cleaner code. Also because of @Will Ness I stopped using the last of of 2s list and switched to one value determining all lengths.

I do think recursively defined lists are more efficient, the previous number multiplied by a factor.

Just separating the function into two doesn't make a difference so the 3 and 5 multiples would be

```
m35 lim = mergeAll $ 
          map (takeWhile (<=lim).iterate (*3)) $
               takeWhile (<=lim).iterate (*5)  $ 1
```

And the 2s each multiplied by the product of 3s and 5s

```
ham n = mergeAll $
        map (takeWhile (<=lim).iterate (*2)) $ m35 lim 
    where lim= 2^n
```

After editing the function I ran it

`last $ ham 50`

1125899906842624

(0.00 secs, 7,029,728 bytes)

then

`last $ ham 100`

1267650600228229401496703205376

(0.03 secs, 64,395,928 bytes)

It is probably better to use `10^n` but for comparison I again used `2^n`

**5/11/2019**

Because I so prefer infinite and recursive lists I became a bit obsessed with making these infinite.

I was so impressed and inspired with @Daniel Wagner and his `Data.Universe.Helpers` I started using `+*+` and `+++` but then added my own infinite list. I had to `mergeAll` my list to work but then realized the infinite 3 and 5 multiples were exactly what they should be. So, I added the 2s and `mergeAll`d everything and they came out. Before, I stupidly thought `mergeAll` would not handle infinite list but it does most marvelously.

When a list is infinite in Haskell, Haskell calculates just what is needed, that is, is lazy. The adjunct is that it does calculate from, the start.

Now, since Haskell multiples until the limit of what is wanted, no limit is needed in the function, that is, no more `takeWhile`. The speed up is incredible and the memory lowered too,

The following is on my slow home PC with 3GB of RAM.

```
tia = mergeAll.map (iterate (*2)) $
      mergeAll.map (iterate (*3)) $ iterate (*5) 1
```

last $ take 10000 tia

288325195312500000

(0.02 secs, 5,861,656 bytes)

**6.5.2019**
I learned how to `ghc -02` So the following is for 50000 Hammings to 2.38E+30. And this is further proof my code is garbage.

```
INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.000s  (  0.916s elapsed)
GC      time    0.047s  (  0.041s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.005s elapsed)
Total   time    0.047s  (  0.962s elapsed)

Alloc rate    0 bytes per MUT second
Productivity   0.0% of total user, 95.8% of total elapsed
```

**6.13.2019**

@Will Ness rawks. He provided a clean and elegant revision of `tia` above and it proved to be five times as fast in `GHCi`. When I `ghc -O2 +RTS -s` his against mine, mine was several times as fast. There had to be a compromise.

So, I started reading about fusion that I had encountered in R. Bird's ***Thinking Functionally with Haskell*** and almost immediately tried this.

```
mai n = mergeAll.map (iterate (*n))
mai 2 $ mai 3 $ iterate (*5) 1
```

It matched Will's at 0.08 for 100K Hammings in `GHCi` but what really surprised me is (also for 100K Hammings.) this and especially the elapsed times. 100K is up to 2.9e+38.

```
 TASKS: 3 (1 bound, 2 peak workers (2 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    0 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity 100.0% of total user, 90.2% of total elapsed
```

Comment: GoalKicker.com “XXX for Professionals” books are copies of "Documentation" that once was a part of SO (it says so itself). But thanks for the link, it's nice to have it all in one place, nicely formatted, and accessible again. Didn't know about it, at all, before this.

Comment: `comp = sort $ [e | d <- threes 26, e <- list d] = sort $ [e | d <- scanl (\a b -> a*b) 1 $ replicate 26 3, e <- scanl (\a b -> a*b) d $ replicate 16 5] = sort $ concat [scanl (\a b -> a*b) d $ replicate 16 5 | d <- scanl (\a b -> a*b) 1 $ replicate 26 3] = sort $ join [scanl (\a b -> a*b) d $ replicate 16 5 | d <- scanl (\a b -> a*b) 1 $ replicate 26 3] = sort . join $ [scanl (*) d $ replicate 16 5 | d <- scanl (*) 1 $ replicate 26 3] = sorted_join $ [take 17 $ iterate (*5) d | d <- take 27 $ iterate (*3) 1] = sorted_join [ iterate (*5) d | d <- iterate (*3) 1] =`

Comment: `= sorted_join ( map (iterate (*5)) (iterate (*3) 1) ) = sorted_join . map (iterate (*5)) . iterate (*3) $ 1`

Comment: All well and good, impressive and thank you so much.
It is the changes reflected in `newcomb` that is my heuristic. Diagonalized `'newcomb` generates *all* unique 3's & 5's. The function `ham2` now supplies the 2's & merges. Now, I can generate the 2s like I do the 3s & 5s. I thought them intractable. 
I want to try it before going on to other logic. 
I am now diagonalizing the function. This is fascinating. `newcomb` values become initial values of 2s lists. 3s are initial values of 3s & 5s lists. They can be concatenated & sorted.

Comment: I just corrected a typo in `comp` earlier today. It should have read `[ e*d | e<-....`

Comment: I don't think it should. ---- in case you didn't see this, here's [a link](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~cs410aph/Lectures/Smalltalk%20II/Dijkstra%20on%20Hamming's%20Problem.pdf). also, of course, [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#Haskell).

Comment: 'comp' will not work correctly without it. I have Dijkstra's book. I just can't find it. I have books on three floors. And beside, `comp` has been replaced by `newcomb` that diagonalizes. `newcomb` supplies *all* 3s&5s so the function only has to supply the 2s but now I can generate the 2s like I did the 3s&5s so the function will go away completely and in it's place concatenation & sort of two lists.

Comment: consider `gnf n f = scanl (*) 1 $ replicate f n = take f $ iterate (*n) 1`. later you multiply the numbers from `gnf 3 n` and `gnf 5 n`, and filter out those not `<= c`. But if `t*f <= c` then certainly it must be `t <= c` and `f*t <= c`. so we gaze back at `take f ...` and realize, why produce `f` numbers only to then filter them out, if we can stop producing them in the first place: `mk35 c = [ m | t <- takeWhile (<= c) $ iterate (*3) 1, f <- takeWhile ((<= c).(*t)) $ iterate (*5) 1, m<- [t*f]] ; mkHams c = sort [ m | t <- mk35 c, f <- takeWhile ((<= c).(*t)) $ iterate (*2) 1, m<- [t*f]]`.

Comment: and you are still producing them out of order and then sort; the trick is to produce each stream in increasing order and merge them up preserving that order. and then this will get you that "known algorithm" from which the question *starts*, and asks for an *improvement* to. and the answer was already given many years ago. :) :) if maybe you'd post these musings on Github, &ping me here (or others, elsewhere, like reddit, irc etc.) I'm sure we'd get the discussion going over there, which is a more appropriate place for it, as SO is not a place for having discussions, by design of its owners.

Comment: in case it's unclear, `((<= c) . (*t))` is a function which checks whether a number is `<= c` after being multiplied by `t`. Cheers, and happy trails.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#Haskell but let's have these discussions somewhere else.

Comment: notice that `mergeAll` *is* [`sorted_join`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480291/new-state-of-the-art-in-unlimited-generation-of-hamming-sequence/53938931#comment94884317_53938931). :) also, `tia` can be written more generally as `foldr (\p -> mergeAll . map (iterate (*p))) [1] [2,3,5]`.  (and you meant `ghc -O2` with `+RTS -s` of course, not `-02`).

Comment: "This implementation of `mergeAll` uses a tree of comparisons, and is based on input from Dave Bayer, Heinrich Apfelmus, Omar Antolin Camarena, and Will Ness." -- I use `mergeAll` also because it truncates each infinite sublist of a set according to the result asked for. You got me to realize that limits are arbitrary and I thought the Cartesian product diagonal was fixed. `tails` and `intits` produce diagonals so why not others?